# 0% appearing in the bottom of graph saeborn.catplot

Tags: python, seaborn

i am facing a problem using below code:
link of dataset (df): https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/468/online+shoppers+purchasing+intention+dataset

```
x,y = 'VisitorType', 'Weekend'
df1 = df.groupby(x)[y].value_counts(normalize=True)
df1 = df1.mul(100)
df1 = df1.rename('percent').reset_index()
g = sns.catplot(x=x,y='percent',hue=y,kind='bar',data=df1, palette=sns.color_palette(['#B8860B', '#556B2F']))
g.ax.set_ylim(0,100)
for p in g.ax.patches:
    txt = str(round(p.get_height(), 2)) + '%'
    txt_x = p.get_x()
    txt_y = p.get_height()
    g.ax.text(txt_x,txt_y,txt)
```

[0% is appearing, see red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ev9.png)

please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: difficult to debug without a [mre], your code is missing the data

Comment: downloaded the data from this link and uploaded csv as df: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/468/online+shoppers+purchasing+intention+dataset

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XTgV.png)

Comment: You seem to e using an old seaborn version. To avoid the zero, you can add a test: `if p.get_height() > 0.049:` around the inner part of the `for` loop. Anyway, it is easier to call `for bars in g.ax.containers: g.ax.bar_label(bars, fmt='.2f'%)`.  (Also, `palette=sns.color_palette(['#B8860B', '#556B2F'])` can be written simpler as `palette=['#B8860B', '#556B2F']`).